# How to use luke check nutch index

Tags: indexing, nutch, lucene, luke

I'm using the nutch 1.7 version.

Crawl the end, I have the results file.

Whether I open any files in this directory will appear under this error.

Please,How to use luke check index in this results file?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you open that segments directory, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for you.I have resolved the problem.Because there is no index to solr.